# Lesson Plan Template: drop-down list in spreadsheet cell pulling in other drop-down lists

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a school teacher in the process of creating a lesson plan template for our elementary school using a Google spreadsheet. I want to make this template customizable for grades k-5 and also to incorporate drop-down lists of the Common Core State Standards (which we are now required to include in our weekly plans).

Here is a link to my progress so far:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmawmBcNyfAbdGozZHJObmlkcVpfdHRYQmlXU0JESmc&usp=sharing

Because there are different common core standards for each grade level, I would like the teacher to be able do the following:

1. Select her grade level from a drop-down menu
2. Select the subject (Math, Reading, Writing, etc.) from a drop-down menu
3. Populate a 'Standards' cell with the common core standard for the selected grade level/subject.

For example, a teacher first selects 'Fifth Grade', then Selects 'Math', and then is able to select the appropriate common core standard for 5th Grade Math: 'CCSS.Math.Content.5.NF.B.7 Apply and extend previous understandings of division to divide unit fractions by whole numbers and whole numbers by unit fractions'

Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of computer programming. I have spent several hours trying to search for a template containing this functionality and the closest I came to a possible solution was here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdGltVUplSUJydzhETjllMDNXZF85ckE&usp=sharing

So my question is, is there a way to incorporate drop-down lists in the way I have described using Google's existing spreadsheet functionality, or will I need to include some type of 3rd party script?

Mark Butler
5th Grade Teacher
Springfield, IL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible, and without using script code. Make the droplist by putting validation+from range.
That range points to a range that has a =query cell formula. The query is made by filtering a master course table based on the cells already typed.
Start with that.

Comment: Well, it almost works. I can only add 2 subjects...  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmawmBcNyfAbdHFuQ2dmcWJRZ3plbF9fazdKTDVPRWc&usp=sharing

Comment: wheres the "query" formula in there?

Comment: Hey Zig, I appreciate that you are giving me pointers rather than step by step directions. (Which is what I would have preferred, but would not have learned from!) I will need to do a little research here, before proceeding. I'll keep you posted. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have found a youtube video that explains how to solve my problem, step by step... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDK8rjdE85Y

Comment: saw that video, its a very cumbersome way to do it, and very hard to maintain. You would have to write down every possible combination of lists that you need beforehand, and because it uses named ranges, those wont update when you change the lists later. Try it with query. I will see if I get some free time to show an example here. And yea sorry for the pointers-only, I do it mostly because of lack of time.

Comment: here is a sample. make a copy of this spreadsheet. now the drawback here is that you need to have a separate query for each row that has dropdown lists. Note that the droplist in droplist!C3 changes as you select different items in A3 and/or B3. The magic happens in the query in data!E1, which could be made more sophisticated for example to check that both A3 and B3 are filled. https://docs.google.com/a/cloudware360.com.pe/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuP6m1j2b6F4dFBJOFRkdnJDaEhJekgwN0xtaG9CWnc#gid=1

Comment: Hi Zig, This works beautifully! If only I could figure out how to add learning standards. Each time I try to do so, when I go back to my drop-down list, #N/A is displayed. Thanks for your patience! This is going to be excellent for our teachers, once I can get it all straightened out.  Here's where I am at... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmawmBcNyfAbdEs0WU5NYktYcTQyVUhZZ0hhcXdlN1E&usp=sharing

Comment: aha, the problem now is that your "grade" is actually a number, not a string, thus the "query" is getting confused because the number is between 'quotes'. This will only work if all your grades are always numbers by removing quotes as in "select A where B='"&droplist!B3&"' AND C="&droplist!A3   if all your grades are not numbers I suggest prefixing all the numbers with a letter as in G4, G5 instead of 4, 5 etc

Comment: That worked! I have one other related question: I would like to move the droplists around on the spreadsheet: for example, the 'Grade' droplist will be part of the lesson plan title. (see spreadsheet Sheet3 @ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmawmBcNyfAbdEs0WU5NYktYcTQyVUhZZ0hhcXdlN1E&usp=sharing) When I do this, the drop lists no longer function properly. Do I need to modify any of the formulas? Thanks so much for your help. I'm also going to make this template freely available online for teachers and will credit you for your drop-down functionality solution if you like!  Mark

Comment: if you cut+paste them they will work, otherwise you do have to update formulas because the "query" cell references your two droplists. Google updates formulas automatically only if you cut+paste cells. note the query is =query(A2:C;"select A where B='"&droplist!B4&"' AND C='"&droplist!A4&"'") and references A4 and B4 from droplist sheet.

Comment: I did cut and paste the 3 cells from the droplist page, to sheet3, but the droplists only seem to display whatever was preselected on the droplist sheet. I tried deleting the droplist sheet, but then got a #name? in the 3rd droplist. My idea of having 'Grade' in the title of the template is flawed because the teacher will have to go back and reselect the same grade level in order to access different standards from the 2nd & 3rd droplists. It might be better to create separate templates for each grade level- which would only require 2 droplists. Thanks for your time.  Mark

Comment: aha, seems like cut&paste doesnt correctly shift the "list validation", so you would need to re-do the cell validation for new droplists.

Comment: Hello Zig, When I duplicate the drop list for a second subject, the 3rd drop-down list returns the list that was selected for the 1st subject. My email is bradfdlad@gmail.com Can I email you privately?

Comment: I covered that in a previous comment regarding the drawbacks, and also in data!F2 :)

Comment: You sure did! Your solution is very elegant. It just took me a while to figure out how the formulas are functioning. I made separate 'output' columns for each droplist pair and it works just fine. Thanks again, Zig :-)  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoYYyfJwkNsudGljNjdEQWlSc0hKUkI0SU1Lb2FrMHc&usp=sharing