# Apps Script: is there a way to show an autocomplete list (from data from other sheet) not in a UI above the sheet, but in the same cell I'm editing?

Tags: autocomplete, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872157/google-apps-script-how-to-make-suggest-box-library-to-work) there is orientation on how to get a UI that shows an autocomplete list (e.g., of emails). 
Now I'd like to know: is there a way to show an autocomplete list (from data from other sheet) not in a UI above the sheet, but in the same cell I'm editing by typping?

Comment: Looks like you could use data validation to get almost the same functionality ( or not ?)

Comment: But can I insert data validation from other spreadsheet? I think not...

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. Serge's suggestion should cover most cases. You can do dynamic  validation lists (recently I answered a s.o. about just that, see [Lesson Plan Template: drop-down list in spreadsheet cell pulling in other drop-down lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302936/lesson-plan-template-drop-down-list-in-spreadsheet-cell-pulling-in-other-drop-d)